# Query work with localhost and not work in live server

Tags: php, mysql

Everyone, this mysql query is working properly on localhost

```
                $query3 = "SELECT tutor_category_subject.subject_id, GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT subject.subjects SEPARATOR ', ') AS teaching_subjects  
                            FROM tutor_category_subject
                            INNER JOIN subject ON tutor_category_subject.subject_id = subject.subject_id
                            WHERE tutor_category_subject.tutor_id = $teacherId";
```

But on uploading it to the live server, it's not working and I get this error message.

> Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP
>   columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause

This is my query output without GROUP BY clause.

```
 +------------+-------------------------------+
| subject_id | teaching_subjects             |
+------------+-------------------------------+
|          8 | Art & Craft                   |
|         10 | Buddhism                      |
|         12 | Catholicism                   |
|         14 | Christianity                  |
|         16 | Dancing                       |
|         34 | Accounting                    |
|         37 | Business Studies              |
|         39 | Conbined Mathematics          |
|         42 | General Infomation Technology |
+------------+-------------------------------+
```

Can someone tell me what the problem might be?

Thank you

describe tables

```
mysql> describe tutor_category_subject;
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| tcs_id      | int(4) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| tutor_id    | int(4) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| category_id | int(2) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| subject_id  | int(4) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

mysql> describe subject;
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type            | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| subject_id | int(2) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| subjects   | varchar(60)     | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I need to select subjects to a particular tutor. One tutor could have more subjects. thats why I used 'GROUP_CONTACT()' in my query. Without group by clause query is working in local host. But not in online.

Comment: have you tried executing the actual sql on the phpmyadmin side?

Comment: no.. I tried with mysql command prompt

Comment: Can you run `DESCRIBE tutor_category_subject` and `DESCRIBE subject` and actually describe what you want the query to do in words?

Comment: I described my tables in my question.

Comment: So you want to have all subject, that one specific teacher teaches? The sample output from the query, is that the result you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message tells you why that happens: You need a [`GROUP BY`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) clause.

It's difficult to say what exactly you want to group on without knowing what the query should do and what your data is.

I'm not sure whether I have understood correctly what you want, try whether this does the correct thing for you:

```
SELECT s.subject_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT s.subjects)
FROM tutor_category_subject AS tcs
INNER JOIN subject as s 
    ON tcs.subject_id = s.subject_id
GROUP BY tcs.category_id
WHERE tcs.tutor_id = $teacherId
```

Pay attention to SQL injections for `$teacherId`

As you can see, I have completely removed the `GROUP`ing stuff. If your query yields a result, where you would like to combine multiple rows into one, that is when you need `GROUP_BY my_column`: merge those, that have an equal value in column `my_column`. [Aggregate Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) are used to control how exactly the other columns are merged.

Comment: how can I use GROUP BY clause in this query? I tried with GROUP BY subject_id and GROUP BY subjects. But it is not working

Comment: @user1543817 Can you try to explain what the query should do? Also include the table layout. Please edit it into your question.

Comment: @user1543817 I have revised my answer, see if that works for you. If not, describe what you would expect instead.

Comment: But in my case, the same subject may have much more time to a particular tutor under different categories. Thats why I used GROUP_CONTACT() and 'distinct' to avoid to select one subject many time in my query.

Comment: @user1543817 Ah I see. I have modified the query according to what I've understood.